# Graph in SSRS only shows a couple of week's data

Tags: reporting-services, graph, mdx

I'm making a graph in SSRS which will highlight the sales for each week from a specific week, and from 52 week up to that date.

For this I have created the following data set in SSRS:

```
WITH SET LAST52WEEKS AS
    {   
        STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Week].&[2017]&[1]&[1]&[4]").Lag(52):
        STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Week].&[2017]&[1]&[1]&[4]")
    }
Select {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON 0,
{Last52Weeks} ON 1
FROM (
    Select {
        [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024]
        } on columns
    from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1]
    )
```

which works as intended, and have an output for week `13` through `4` with each week having a weekly sales `Quantity>400` (except for one week with Quantity (null).

However, when I add this data as the Y-axis in a graph in SSRS along with `Weeks` attribute as the X-axis, only four rows are returned. The rows returned are for the weeks

`1,19,3,40`

All other values are blank in the graph. Does anyone have any idea as to why this may occur?

Regards,

Cenderze

> EDIT updated x-axis from using Interval value = 1

When I changed the `Interval value` under `Horizontal Axis Properties` I now get the following values for the x-axis:

> **1**, 13, 14,[...],19, **2**, 20, 21, 22, 23, [...], 29, **3**, 30, 31, 32,[...],39, **4**, 41, 42,[...], 53

where I have **bolded** the results which seem odd. Im guessing these values are the `quarters`? I am however using `Weeks` as my Grouping variable.

> EDIT

Following Mike Honey I figured that:

```
WITH SET LAST52WEEKS AS
    {STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Date].&[1]&[2017-01-29]").Parent.Lag(52)
    :
    STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Date].&[1]&[2017-01-29]").parent}
Select {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON 0,
{Last52Weeks} ON 1
FROM (
    Select {
        [Dim Store2].[Store Key].&[1024]
    } on columns
from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1])
```

ought to work, but it simply returned that Quantity was (null). Why isn't this equivalent to the other Query I wrote, but based off of Date rather than week?

> EDIT

I also noted that the graph I am creating has week 52 to the utmost right, whereas it is supposed to have week 4 at the utmost right.

> EDIT

[image]

> EDIT

Edited the Query to become:

```
WITH SET LAST52WEEKS AS
{STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Hierarchy].&[2017 W4]").Lag(52):STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Hierarchy].&[2017 W4]")}
Select {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON 0,
{(Last52Weeks,[Dim Store2].[Store Name].Allmembers)} ON 1
from [DSV_FactStoreSales 1]
```

where Hierarchy is an Attribute Hierarchy with the values `2010 W1`,...., `2018 W52`.

But this yields me an output:

```
2016 W40    Store1  300
2016 W40    Store2  400
...
2017 W39    Store1  400
```

where I would expect the output to be:

```
2016 W4 Store1  300
2016 W4 Store2  400
...
2017 W4 Store1  400
```

Any ideas? It is just an hierarchy with one attribute, `Week Name` (I've tried the Query with both using `[Dim Date].[Hierarchy].[Week Name].&[2017 W4]` and `[Dim date].[Hierarchy].&[2017 W4]`, both with the same output.

> EDIT (very close now!)

[image]

Comment: Any screenshots?

Comment: We need to see the structure of your [Dim Date] dimension.  I'm guessing [Week] is a hierarchy with 4 levels? I suspect you should instead use the attribute hierarchy from the lowest level.

Comment: @MikeHoney     Yes, exactly. The [Dim Date] dimension is a 5 level hierarchy with the levels being YQMWD. The strangest thing was when I deleted some moot variables, I got the graph to show the correct data. However, using a new data set and sorting the data based on StoreKeys yield the same type of graph with only showing 4 dates.

Comment: @MikeHoney     Just to clarify, you suggest to create the MDX Query based on the dates instead, and use a .lag(365) instead of .lag(52) for weeks?

Comment: @MikeHoney     I tried to implement a solution based off of dates, but it didn't work. I edited it in the OP. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @DanyloKorostil Thanks for replying! Sorry for the delay, but I've uploaded an image now. Rather small, but when you click on it I believe it's a good size.

Comment: So, your only problem is sorting, right?

Comment: Ah, sorry, ignore my last reply. I don't understand what is from 1 to 4? Could you try https://pastebin.com/raw/AqmU7zn2 ?

Comment: I would look for an Attribute Hierarchy (a single-level hierarchy) that contains the Year + Week values.  If this doesn't exist you may need to create it.  Then I would try the .Lag(52) method (without .parent).

Comment: Screen shots of your dimension structure would help - the hierarchies and attributes.

Comment: @MikeHoney     So close now, will update OP in a min or two.

Comment: @MikeHoney     I noticed a warning "Attribute relationships do not exist between one or more levels in this hierarchy" in the original hierarchy showing YQMWD, may this have some unexpected results? The warning only shows on Date, the rest of the levels seems to be mapped.

Comment: You have to set something like that: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/erin_welker/WindowsLiveWriter/UsingSSAS2008toolswithSSAS2005cubes_9AE0/Attribute%20Relationship%20designer%202_2.jpg

Comment: Your output from using [Dim Date].[Hierarchy] appears identical to your expected output. Typo?

Comment: @MikeHoney     yes it was a typo! Adjusted it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues I can see with your current chart. One is that your week numbers are being treated as text, which is why the ordering has sequences like `19, 2, 20`. The other is that it isn't distinguishing where the week numbers for one year ends and another year starts.

I'm not familiar with mdx. I'm hoping you're able to make a simple dataset that is purely a list of sales with dates. For my solution, I used an Oracle query like:

```
SELECT date SALEDATE, ID FROM sales
WHERE date BETWEEN '28-MAR-2016' AND '28-JAN-2017'
```

With a new chart, use `[Count(ID)]` for the values. It then needs two category groups, first one for the year and then one for the week number. You can use expressions to get these from a date field. For the first category group, set `Group on:` and `Label` as

```
=DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Fields!SALEDATE.Value)
```

and for the second, set `Group on:` and `Label` as

```
=DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!SALEDATE.Value)
```

[image: Chart design with count(id) and two category groups]

To then hide the columns with under 400 sales, right-click the second category group (the weeks one) and add a filter: `[Count(ID)] (integer) > 400`.

[image: filter count(id) > 400]

Even if your dataset is different from the raw data approach I'm using, hopefully this will steer you in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: @PeteRennardCumming Thanks for replying! I hope this is possible to create in my solution. The labels in the graph was very clean. Why is it required to use trunc()?

Comment: The `trunc()` probably wasn't necessary, since you just use the DateParts in the report. I've removed them from my answer to simplify it. You can always add a truncated date as an extra column if you include charts by day.

Comment: @PeteRennardCumming I didn't quite understand why you use two Category groups. I tried to implement that but it differed vastly from what you did. Do you use two categories with the same expressions on Group On and Label, or do you use `=DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Fields!SALEDATE.Value)` for Group on and `=DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Fields!SALEDATE.Value` as the Label option, and then apply the same logic replacing DatePart(DateInterval, Year with DatePart(DateInterval,Week?

Comment: It's the latter, use a different formula for each category group. I've clarified this in my answer now.

Comment: You could use instead one category group that groups on both the formulas, and concatenate the values for the label. By using two category groups, you get the 2016 and 2017 spanners around all the relevant columns, rather than having the year label repeat for every column.

Comment: @PeteRennardCumming I've done some tweaking, and now I am very close. I've edited the OP with a Picture of my current progress. Do you have any idea why 2017 is filtered Before 2016? I've used the updated Expressions you've written as I very much fancy the way you've done the graph.

Comment: @PeteRennardCumming Finally! The Sorting of one of the expression was set to Weeks, I adjusted it to become date as well. Now it finally works! By the way, the `|---------|` appearence under your graph, where do you adjust that? I didn't find any options when I tried to alter the category groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139982/discussion-between-pete-rennard-cumming-and-cenderze).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the x-axis and choose "Horizontal Axis Properties".  Under Axis Options change the Interval value from Auto to 1.

Comment: Thanks for replying! However, I still have the same issue. But this added some additional insight into the issue. Using Interval value 1 I now see every value on the x-axis, but it is clustered in a weird (quarterly?) way. I will update the OP with the values I have on my x-axis.